# How to read a numpy boolean array in R?

Tags: r, numpy

I tried reading into R a boolean vector stored as a numpy array (.npy) with `RcppCNPy` package like this:

```
arr <- npyLoad("path/to/file/boolean_array.npy")
```

But instead of a boolean vector I get some numeric vector. Any way to read this directly into R without having to read it in python and storing it as txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:

The only way I found so far without modifying the `numpy` array itself is to use the [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) package in R:

> The reticulate package provides a comprehensive set of tools for interoperability between Python and R. The package includes facilities for translation between R and Python objects (for example, between R and Pandas data frames, or between R matrices and NumPy arrays).

Usage would be like this:

```r
library("reticulate")

np <- import("numpy")
arr <- np$load("path/to/file/boolean_array.npy")
```

**Note** that this library will however require a Python environment and might need to install [`rminiconda`](https://github.com/hafen/rminiconda).

---

Alternative:
**Modification of the numpy file iteself**

Assuming you had control over the way the array is saved in Python, one way would be to save the `numpy` array with type `int` and then load it as an integer array in `R` as well. You could then use the `as.logical()` function to convert it to a boolean array in R again.

The part in Python:

```py
import numpy as np


arr = np.array([True, False, False, True, True])
np.save("path/to/file/boolean_array.npy", arr.astype(int))
```

The part in R:

```r
library("RcppCNPy")

arr <- as.logical(npyLoad("path/to/file/boolean_array.npy", type = 'integer'))
arr

[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: The .npy file is actually the output from an external tool, so I can't change it. Of course I could read again the file in python and save it as txt file, but my question was if there is anyway to read this boolean numpy array directly from R. The as.logical() trick didn't work since the output is a boolean array and not an integer array. Thanks for the advice anyway

Comment: @mfalco no worries. I was dissatisfied with the solution myself and investigated a bit more. I think this is an interesting issue you came across. You can check my edited answer. Hope it resolves the problem now.

Comment: Sadly, I think that is the only option at the moment, although its not very optimized. Thanks a lot for the research effort!